# How to nevigate from child tag to parent tag to get the xpath in android mobile automation using web driver

Tags: mobile, xpath, automation, webdriver, appium

We have requirement to construct the Xpath in android mobile automation using selenium web driver.

Yes, we have resources-id, text to identify the element but, specifically we are looking for constructing the xpaths by navigating through tags.

In web based application automation, we have xpath checker for constructing the locator. Likewise, are any other tools to get the xpath in android mobile automation using web driver?

Any suggestions/help along with the XML tag would be appreciated....

Thanks&Regards,

Matti

Answer (score 0):

If you are using "WebDriver", then finding the parent element of webelement could be easily achieved by tweeking the xpath.

You can try using "ancestor" or "ancestor-or-self" or "parent"

Example :

```
//input[@name='q']/parent::div
```

Hope this works.

Comment: Thank you Praveen for your reply..I have used same concept in web based application by using /../ to navigate back to parent tag but, I want same kind of approach in automating mobile application(Webdriver+Appium+Android)...Thanks&Regards,Matti